# Using pdf.js to render a PDF but it doesn't work and I don't get any error messages to help me debug the issue

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

I'm trying to build a Flask app where I upload pdf's and I'm working on previewing them before submitting to the back-end.

The script I'm using is as follows:

```
const imageUploadValidation = (function () {
  "use strict";

  pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc =
    "https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js";

  const onFilePicked = function (event) {
    // Select file Nodelist containing 1 file
    const files = event.target.files;
    const filename = files[0].name;
    if (filename.lastIndexOf(".") <= 0) {
      return alert("Please add a valid file!");
    }

    const fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = function (e) {
      const pdfData = e.target.result;

      let loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({ data: pdfData })
      loadingTask.promise.then(function (pdf) {
          console.log("PDF loaded", pdf);

          pdf.getPage(1).then((page) => {
            console.log("page loaded", page);
            // var scale = 1.5;
            // var viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: scale });

            var iframe = document.getElementById("image-preview");
            iframe.src = page
            // var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            // canvas.height = viewport.height;
            // canvas.width = viewport.width;

            // var renderContext = {
            //   canvasContext: context,
            //   viewport: viewport,
            // };

            // var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
            // renderTask.promise.then(function () {
            //   console.log("Page rendered");
            // });
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    };
    const pdf = fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(files[0]);
    console.log("read as Data URL", pdf);
  };

  const Constructor = function (selector) {
    const publicAPI = {};

    const changeHandler = (e) => {
      // console.log(e)
      onFilePicked(e);
    };

    publicAPI.init = function (selector) {
      // Check for errors.
      const fileInput = document.querySelector(selector);
      if (!selector || typeof selector !== "string") {
        throw new Error("Please provide a valid selector");
      }

      fileInput.addEventListener("change", changeHandler);
    };

    publicAPI.init(selector);
    return publicAPI;
  };

  return Constructor;
})();

imageUploadValidation("form input[type=file]");
```

The loading task promise never seems to run. Everything seems to work up until that point. I'm not familiar with this Promise syntax, so I can't be sure if the problem is there or how I'm passing in the pdf file.

P.S. The commented out code is the original way I had this setup, what
s uncommented was just me testing a different way.

Answer (score 10):

### **Check Datatype**

First you might want to check what your getting back from your `FileReader`, specifically what is the datatype for `pdfData`. If you have a look at the documentation ([direct link](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/5cf116a958548f6596674bf8d5ca0fe64aa2df3c/src/display/api.js#L115)) `getDocument` is expecting a Unit8Array or a binary string.

### **Add Missing Parameters**

The next problem you have is your missing required parameters in your call to `getDocument`. Here is the minimum required arguments:

```
var args = {
    url: 'https://example.com/the-pdf-to-load.pdf',
    cMapUrl: "./cmaps/",
    cMapPacked: true,
}
```

I have never used the `data` argument in place of the `url` but as long as you supply the correct datatype you should be fine. Notice that `cMapUrl` should be a relative or absolute path to the cmap folder. PDFJS often needs these files to actually interpret a PDF file. Here are all the files from the demo repository (GitHub pages): [cmaps](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/gh-pages/web/cmaps) You'll need to add these to your project.

Instead of using `data` I would recommend uploading your files as blobs and then all you have to do is supply the blob URL as `url`. I am not familiar with how to do that, I just know its possible in modern browsers.

### **Where Is Your Viewer / You Don't Need iFrame or Canvas**

PDFJS just needs a div to place the PDF inside of. It's picky about some of the CSS rules, for exmaple it MUST be positioned absolute, otherwise PDFJS generates the pages as 0px height.

I don't see `PDFViewer` or `PDFLinkService` in your code. It looks like you are trying to build the entire viewer from scratch yourself. This is no small endeavor. When you get `loadingTask` working correctly the response should be handled something like this:

```
loadingTask.promise.then(
    // Success function.
    function( doc ) {
        // viewer is holding: new pdfjsViewer.PDFViewer()
        // linkService is: new pdfjsViewer.PDFLinkService()
        viewer.setDocument( doc );
        linkService.setDocument( doc );
    },
    // Error function.
    function( exception ) {
        // What type of error occurred?
        if ( exception.name == 'PasswordException' ) {
            // Password missing, prompt the user and try again.
            elem.appendChild( getPdfPasswordBox() );
        } else {
            // Some other error, stop trying to load this PDF.
            console.error( exception );
        }
        /**
         * Additional exceptions can be reversed engineered from here:
         * https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/mobile-viewer/viewer.js
         */
    }
);
```

Notice that `PDFViewer`  does all the hard work for you. `PDFLinkService` is needed if you want links in the PDF to work. You really should checkout the [live demo](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html) and the [example files](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples).

Its a lot of work but these [example files specifically](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/components) can teach you all you need to know about PDFJS.

### **Example / Sample Code**

Here is some sample code from a project I did with PDFJS. The code is a bit advanced but it should help you reverse engineer how PDFJS is working under the hood a bit better.

`pdfObj` = An object to store all the info and objects for this PDF file. I load multiple PDFs on a single page so I need this to keep them separate from each other.

`updatePageInfo` = My custome function that is called by PDFJS's eventBus when the user changes pages in the PDF; this happens as they scroll from page to page.

`pdfjsViewer.DownloadManager` = I allow users to download the PDFs so I need to use this.

`pdfjsViewer.EventBus` = Handles events like loading, page changing, and so on for the PDF. I am not 100% certain but I think the `PDFViewer` requires this.

`pdfjsViewer.PDFViewer` = What handles actually showing your PDF to users. `container` is the element on the page to render in, remember it must be positioned absolute.

```
// Create a new PDF object for this PDF.
var pdfObj = {
    'container': elem.querySelector('.pdf-view-wrapper'),
    'document': null,
    'download': new pdfjsViewer.DownloadManager(),
    'eventBus': new pdfjsViewer.EventBus(),
    'history': null,
    'id': id,
    'linkService': null,
    'loaded': 0,
    'loader': null,
    'pageTotal': 0,
    'src': elem.dataset.pdf,
    'timeoutCount': 0,
    'viewer': null
};

// Update the eventBus to dispatch page change events to our own function.
pdfObj.eventBus.on( 'pagechanging', function pagechange(evt) { 
    updatePageInfo( evt );
} );

// Create and attach the PDFLinkService that handles links and navigation in the viewer.
var linkService = new pdfjsViewer.PDFLinkService( {
    'eventBus': pdfObj.eventBus,
    'externalLinkEnabled': true,
    'externalLinkRel': 'noopener noreferrer nofollow',
    'externalLinkTarget': 2 // Blank
} );
pdfObj.linkService = linkService;

// Create the actual PDFViewer that shows the PDF to the user.
var pdfViewer = new pdfjsViewer.PDFViewer(
    {
        'container': pdfObj.container,
        'enableScripting': false, // Block embeded scripts for security
        'enableWebGL': true,
        'eventBus': pdfObj.eventBus,
        'linkService': pdfObj.linkService,
        'renderInteractiveForms': true, // Allow form fields to be editable
        'textLayerMode': 2
    }
);
pdfObj.viewer = pdfViewer;
pdfObj.linkService.setViewer( pdfObj.viewer );
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for all of this information, this is very useful. I was about to give up on being able to get this done and just saw your answer. I will look into testing this out as soon as possible. Thank you very much!!

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to up vote and mark as answered if this helps you solve your problem.

Comment: @Blizzardengle what is pdfjsViewer? when I tried your code out the compiler told me that it doesnt exist. How do I set it up? what library do I need to reference in my project to get it to work? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @user2529011 pdfjsViewer is the compiled PDFJS library: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js I think I copied a precompiled script from a CDN in my project. The last comment right above the last code block explains what it is and how to use it.